# Using JNI in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp

how to use JNI in JSP page?.In net i found that 
1. because if anything goes seriously wrong in the C part of your application, it will very likely crash your J2EE server, downing all other web services and applications it is running.

2. because the 'reactivatable' nature of web applications means there is no guarantee that a static initializer will not be executed more than once during one JVM run.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're confident of the reliability of your JNI-linked library, I'd *strongly* recommend not doing this, for the reasons you've identified.

I'd recommend decoupling the application server from your native code, and make the native library available via some remote mechanism (e.g. web service / REST / simple socket). That way you've isolated the app server from any fatal problems related to the native code.

Comment: Not sure, not sure. For example, we use Java advanced image io (which includes JNI part) for image resizing from our servlets, and it works stellar.

Comment: Ultimately everything goes to native code. If you're confident of the provenance and reliability of that JNI code + library, then link to it directly. In the environments I typically work in, I can't/won't make that assumption unless I'm very sure of the reliability.